# Why is postgreSQL using 1-based arrays?

Tags: postgresql, array

Why is PostgreSQL using 1-based arrays (first element being at index 1) and not 0-based arrays (first element being at index 0)?

Comment: I guess this was a design decision. Having said that Oracle has done the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I think Postgresql has had arrays since before SQL-99, the SQL-99 standard specifies 1-indexed arrays, and it's consistent with other areas in SQL where the first element is 1 instead of 0.

PostgreSQL actually has support for custom array start indexes, but I strongly advise you not to use it.

Comment: Window ranking functions, too, start from 1: `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: You're right, I thought `position` was 0-indexed. Fixing.